# Refresh access token using authenticatior in retrofit android

Tags: android, authentication, retrofit2, interceptor, refresh-token

How can I refresh my token using authenticator? I need the refresh token method to return the token or null when I get 401 in my api call.

```
class SupportInterceptor() : Interceptor, Authenticator {
    /**
     * Interceptor class for setting of the headers for every request
     */
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()
        request = request?.newBuilder()
            ?.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            ?.addHeader("app-id", "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")
            ?.build()
        return chain.proceed(request)
    }

    /**
     * Returns a request that includes a credential to satisfy an authentication challenge in
     * [response]. Returns null if the challenge cannot be satisfied.
     *
     * The route is best effort, it currently may not always be provided even when logically
     * available. It may also not be provided when an authenticator is re-used manually in an
     * application interceptor, such as when implementing client-specific retries.
     */
    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
        var requestAvailable: Request? = null
        try {

            return runBlocking {
                when (val tokenResponse = refreshToken()) {
                    is Success -> {
                        //                        userPreferences.saveAccessTokens(
                        //                            tokenResponse.value.access_token!!,
                        //                            tokenResponse.value.refresh_token!!
                        //                        )
                        response.request.newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${tokenResponse.value.access_token}")
                            .build()
                    }
                    else -> null
                }
            }

            //            requestAvailable = response?.request?.newBuilder()
            ////                ?.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
            //                ?.build()
            //            return requestAvailable
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
        }
        return requestAvailable
    }


    suspend fun refreshToken(): Either<Failure, String?> {

        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val PREFS_NAME = "userPref"
                val sharedPref: SharedPreferences =
                    context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

                val refreshToken = sharedPref.getString(MyConstants.KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN, "")

                val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseURL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()

                val api: TokenRefreshApi = retrofit.create(TokenRefreshApi::class.java)

                val response = api.refreshAccessToken(refreshToken).execute()

//                val call: Call<LogIn> = api.refreshAccessToken(refreshToken)

                when (response.isSuccessful) {

                    false -> Either.Left(response.errorResponse())

                    true -> {

                        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()

                        editor.putString(
                            MyConstants.KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                            response.body()!!.access_token
                        )
                        editor.putString(
                            MyConstants.KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN,
                            response.body()!!.refresh_token
                        )

                        editor!!.apply()

                        response.body()!!.access_token

                    }

                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Timber.e("searchTasks: $e")
                Either.Left(Failure.UnknownError)
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first clarify the industry standard behavior for reliable clients:

- Client tries an API request with an access token
- If client receives a 401 it attempts to silently refresh the access token and retry the API request with the new token
- If there are technical problems avoid redirecting the user to re-authenticate

Here is some [plain Kotlin code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authguidance/basicmobileapp/api/client/ApiClient.kt#L71) that does this.

Looks to me like Retrofit's Authenticator interface makes this easier, and will do the retry for you. Your code looks mostly correct and similar to mine but without the manual checks for 401s:

- You need to test 401s though, and one way to do this is to add arbitrary characters to an access token during development, to simulate expiry

Comment: can you share code of  refreshAccessToken() method

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is having difficulty same like me.

```
 override fun authenticate(route: Route?, response: Response): Request? {
    var requestAvailable: Request? = null
    try {

        return runBlocking {
            val tokenResponse = getNewToken()
            if (!tokenResponse.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                response.request.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer ${tokenResponse}")
                    .build()
            } else {
                null
            }
        }

    } catch (ex: Exception) {
    }
    return requestAvailable
}

private fun getNewToken(): String? {


    val PREFS_NAME = "userPref"
    val sharedPref: SharedPreferences =
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    val refreshToken: String = sharedPref.getString("refresh_token", "").orEmpty()

    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_API_URL_CONSUMER)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val hashMap = HashMap<String, String>()
    hashMap.put("refresh_token", refreshToken)


    val call = retrofit.create(TokenRefreshApi::class.java).refreshAccessToken(hashMap)

    val authTokenResponse = call?.execute()?.body()

    if (authTokenResponse != null) {


        val editor: SharedPreferences.Editor = sharedPref.edit()
        editor.putString(
            "access_token",
            authTokenResponse!!.access_token
        )
        editor.putString(
            "refresh_token",
            authTokenResponse!!.refresh_token
        )

        editor!!.apply()


        return authTokenResponse!!.access_token
    } else {
        return null
    }
}
```